# compare data between two tables with same structure in hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

How to compare two tables with same structures in hive. I believe minus will not work in hive.

SRC table:

```
id name
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

TGT table:

id name

```
1   A
2   C
3   C
```

can anyone help me with a query.

Answer (score 4):

**If you are looking for equality between two tables and for differences if any, you can do like following**

`SELECT MIN(TableName) as TableName, ID, NAME
 FROM
 (
     SELECT 'SRC_TABLE' as TableName, A.ID, A.NAME
     FROM A
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'TGT_TABLE' as TableName, B.ID, B.NAME
     FROM B
 ) tmp
 GROUP BY ID, NAME
 HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
 ORDER BY ID`

Basically what the above query does is as follows,

- Combines all the records from both the tables & groups them by all columns. Later prints out only those records which are unique [**having count(*) = 1**].
- If the above query prints **zero records** then it means both the tables are **perfectly equal**
- If the above query prints any records at all, then it means those particular records are not present in one or the other tables
- For the above example you listed the output is as follows,

  `[ TBL_NAME  |  ID  |  NAME ]`

  `----------------------------`

  `[ SRC_TABLE |   2  |    B  ]`

  `[ TGT_TABLE |   2  |    C  ]`

**Credits:** I found the above solution from this [website](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/11/10/2737.aspx). I tried it, and it was fantastic!

Comment: Consider the following table A and B, which are legal in hive.Table A :id:1 name:A; id:1 name:A  , Table B: nothing. This sql will give you the wrong answer. So you can not use this sql in Hive.

Answer (score 1):

Minus does not exists in Hive. You can use left join or full join for find different records from both tables.

LEFT JOIN: - allows to find records that not exist in TGT

```
select a.id, a.name 
  from TGT a left join TGT b on a.id=b.id and a.name=b.name
where b.id is null
```

The same may be achieved using `NOT EXISTS`

```
select a.id, a.name 
      from TGT a 
where not exists(select 1 from  TGT b where a.id=b.id and a.name=b.name)
```

FULL JOIN: - allows to find differences from both the tables

```
select a.id as SRC_ID, a.name as SRC_NAME ,
       b.id as TGT_ID, b.name as TGT_NAME
  from TGT a full join TGT b on a.id=b.id and a.name=b.name
where a.id is null OR b.id is null
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I want the data where id is mismatch and name mismatch as well

Comment: what is expected result for your data example?

Comment: My left join query will return `2 B`. Is it correct?

Comment: yes, So  then I need to give all the fileds in left outer join right if i want to compare all fields. For example I have 20 fields , So, Do i need to add all fields in left join

Comment: Yes, you need to add all fields to be compared in JOIN ON condition

Comment: @leftjoin-We can use case statement to compare name field between SRC and TGT right. Like  case when src.name<>tgt.name then 'F' else 'T' end like this

Comment: @ssk Sure, you can write some CASE statements. But anyway need to join because without join it will be cartesian product

Comment: @ssk Maybe you can JOIN only on primary key and use CASE statements for other fields

Comment: Yes we can join the tables on key fields and we can compare the data for non key fields in case statement

Comment: Yes, and filter on those case statements. There are always many possible solutions.

Comment: but if both field has null values then where not exists will not work as null is not equal to null

Comment: @leftjoin is there any workaround for that . I always like your solution .  in which way I can write the where not exists query

Comment: @Kumar It's possible to transform NULLs like this: `nvl(a.id,'')=nvl(b.id,'') ` if you want to match by NULLs. Better use some rare special value for null representation, not to correlate with real empty values . You know in the DWH it is often some special values are being used to represent NULLs, like -999999 for Integer id or 'Unknown' for some string column.  And the same can be done for JOIN conditions.

Comment: @Kumar NULLs will be not joined also. But IMHO it depends on your requirements, how you should treat them. Transform to 'Unknown' if necessary. For dates it can be 1900-01-01. Kimball group's opinion on similar topic: https://www.kimballgroup.com/2003/02/design-tip-43-dealing-with-nulls-in-the-dimensional-model/

Answer (score 1):

```
select      id
           ,SRC_name
           ,TGT_name

from       (select      id
                       ,min   (case tab when 'S' then name end) as SRC_name
                       ,min   (case tab when 'T' then name end) as TGT_name
                       ,count (case tab when 'S' then 1    end) as SRC_count 
                       ,count (case tab when 'T' then 1    end) as TGT_count 

            from        (           select 'S' as tab,id,name from SRC
                        union all   select 'T' as tab,id,name from TGT
                        ) t

            group by    id  
            ) t

having      SRC_count = 0
        or  TGT_count = 0
        or  SRC_name != TGT_name
;
```

If `name` might be NULL or `id` might be non-unique, additional conditions should be added

Comment: Thanks @Dudu for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

To do a full comparison of 2 tables, my experience has shown me that using some checksum mechanism is a more effective and reliable solution than Joining the tables (which gives some difficulties when keys are repeated for instance).

You could have a look at this Python program that handles such comparisons of Hive tables (comparing all the rows and all the columns), and would show you in a webpage the differences that might appear: https://github.com/bolcom/hive_compared_bq

Answer (score 1):

There is a free tool ([dataq.io](http://dataq.io)) which can be used to compare data between two tables in hive. It can visually display the differences.

Disclaimer : I work for dataq.io