# is there any optimised way to write SQL query to find difference between two data-sets?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, hiveql

Following is the query and sample data-set (actual data-set is huge and residing in HDFS)
I am trying to find out the diff in data-set 1 with following query.
Is there any better way to achieve this without using join if possible?

```
SELECT
      dt1.name,
      dt1.code,
      dt1.day
FROM
    dt1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dt2 ON (dt1.name = dt2.name AND dt1.code = dt2.code AND dt1.day = dt2.day)
WHERE
    dt2.name IS NULL AND dt2.code IS NULL AND dt2.day IS NULL
```

following is the data set

```
Data SET 1

name  code  day

a     1001  2019-01-01
a     1002  2019-01-02
a     1003  2019-01-01
b     2001  2019-01-01
b     2002  2019-01-02
b     2003  2019-01-03
```

find out name-code combo of data-set 1 which is not found in data-set 2 for a given day

```
Data SET 2
name  code  day

a     1001  2019-01-01
b     1002  2019-01-01
a     1003  2019-01-01
d     2001  2019-01-01
e     2002  2019-01-01
b     2003  2019-01-01
```

Comment: The `join` should be fine.  What is your problem with it?

Comment: Are you looking for data from SET-1 that are not available in SET-2?

Comment: FULL JOIN allows to find the difference in both tables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42490123/2700344

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Dataset.except](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@except(other:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]) (if you data has duplicated [exceptAll](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@exceptAll(other:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]))

```
val result = dt1.except(dt2)  // Ensure that dt1 and dt2 have the same columns
```

**warning**: Ensure that both datasets have the same column order else generate wrong result (instead of proper exception).

Unfortunately this functionality is not available in spark-sql or Imala/Hive.