# Find the difference between 2 tables

Tags: sql, hive, difference

I have 2 tables and I would like to find the difference between the 2 tables based on email

Table 1 is a history table and has duplicates for emails address but Table 2 has been de-duped for email ( has no duplicates).

Table 1

```
    Email.           validity.   recency.  last Modified
    aa@gmail.com     1                0-3.    1/21/2020
    ab@gmail.com     0                12-16.   1/22/2020
    aa@gmail.com.     1               NULL     12/20/2019
    aa@gmail.com      1               12-16     11/30/2018
    ga@gmail.com.     1                0-3    1/18/2020
```

Table 2

```
    Email.           validity   recency     last Modified type  partner 
    aa@gmail.com     1                0-3    1/21/2020.    C.    Goo
    ab@gmail.com.    0.               12-16.  1/22/2020.    P.   Azz
    ac@gmail.com     1                0-3    1/18/2020.    P.    Goo
```

Expected Output

```
    Email.           validity.   recency.  last Modified
    ga@gmail.com     1            0-3      1/18/2020
```

I would like to find the list of all emails that are present in Table 1 but not table 2. In my understanding, join can only be used to find a subset/similarity. How can I find differences between the 2 tables? Thanks.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42490123/2700344

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT IN` based on key columns.
Assuming `Email` as key column here is sample SQL.

```
SELECT distinct * FROM TABLE1 
WHERE 
validity=1 AND
Email 
NOT IN (
SELECT Email FROM TABLE2 WHERE validity=1
)
```

You can use join as well as you mentioned. In this case just select those that are absent from Table2 and viola you will get non existent records.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON T1.Email = T2.Email
WHERE  T2.Email IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.email = t1.email
                 );
```

You can use `validity` in the logic if that is appropriate.  But the description of the problem does not mention any conditions other than `email`.